# How to solve the below error in my LINQ query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

The SQL query that I wrote to retreive the data I wanted.

```sql
Select JobQuestionType
From JobQuestionTypes AS J
INNER JOIN JobQuestions AS JQ ON J.JobQuestionTypeId = JQ.QuestionType
Where JobId = 3813 AND  Active = 1
Order By JobQuestionId ASC
```

For the above SQL query I wrote the LINQ query using c# as below.

```cs
var questionTypes = _context.JobQuestionTypes.Join(_context.JobQuestions,
        jobQuestionTypes => jobQuestionTypes.JobQuestionTypeId,
        jobQuestions => jobQuestions.JobQuestionType,
        (jobQuestionTypes, recruiters) => new { jobQuestionTypes, recruiters })
        .Where(item => item.JobId.Equals(JobId) && !item.jobQuestionTypes.Active) 
        .Select(item => item.jobQuestionTypes.JobQuestionType).OrderBy(x => x.JobQuestionId).ToList();
```

I am getting an error

> The type arguments for method 'Queryable.Join<TOuter, TInner, TKey,
> TResult>(IQueryable, IEnumerable,
> Expression<Func<TOuter, TKey>>, Expression<Func<TInner, TKey>>,
> Expression<Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from
> the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

How can I solve it. I am new to c#.

(Iam getting the expected output from my sql query. I want to convert it into linq)

Thankyou.

Comment: Probably `jobQuestionTypes.JobQuestionTypeId` and `jobQuestions.JobQuestionType` has different types.

Comment: Don't use JOINs in the first place. LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL. You're using an ORM and entities, not embedded SQL and tables. The whole reason people use ORMs is so they can write object oriented code, with properties, relations and collections, not SQL and JOINs. Your query should be something like `_context.JobQuestionTypes.Where(jt=>jt.Active && jt.Questions.Any(q=>q.JobId=12345)).Select(jt=>jt.JoqQuestionType)`

Comment: The same in query form: `from jq in _context.JobQuestionTypes from q in jq.Questions where jq.Active && q.JobId=12345 select jq.JobQuestionType`. It's EF Core's job to generate JOINs from the relation between JobQuestionType and JobQuestion which is represented by the collection `JobQuestionType.Questions`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Nope..both Are int

Comment: What is `JobQuestionTypes.JobQuestionType` and how does it compare to `JobQuestions.JobQuestionType`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var result= (from j in _context.JobQuestionTypes
join JQ in _context.JobQuestions on j.JobQuestionTypeId equals JQ.QuestionType
where j.JobId = 3813 AND j.Active = 1
orderby j.JobQuestionId
select j.JobQuestionType).FirstOrDefault();
```